# Числительные при перечислении

Tags: числительные, перечисление

Скажите, как верно написать числительные при перечислении в этом случае:
"пяти или десятидолларовая банкнота"?
Верно ли написано? Или надо дефис: "пяти- или десятидолларовая банкнота"?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно — с "висячим дефисом":

***пяти- или десятидолларовая банкнота.***

См. **Полный академический справочник под ред. В.В. Лопатина:**

> **§ 112.** Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами,
> имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего,
> представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют
> «висячим», напр.: *шарико- и роликоподшипники; лит- и изокружки;
> кино-, теле- и видеофильмы; **не двух-, а трёхэтажный дом**; не только
> англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты; как водо-, так и
> газоснабжение; до- или послеперестроечные процессы; либо теле-, либо
> радиопередача; обер- и унтер-офицеры.* Как видно из примеров,
> употребление висячего дефиса не зависит от слитного или дефисного
> написания сложных слов.
>
> http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59

Comment: Спасибо большое!